# How do I get more information about that error?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, debugging, assert

An Qt application is crashing and even debugger mode it's all I get:

> ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file
>   C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore/qlist.h, line 321

That line in the file points to:

```
inline void removeLast() { Q_ASSERT(!isEmpty()); erase(--end()); }
```

But I'd like more information. Like what line exactly in the source code is using it (from search, no direct call to `removeLast()` done).
Is this possible?

Comment: How can any one answer that without seeing your code?

Comment: Did you step through the code to find out where that happens?

Comment: @RSahu: This is from a large code base where I don't even know where does the error come from, that's why I'm asking how I can know more about.

Comment: In that case, your best bet to run the program in a debugger, let the debugger stop when an exception is thrown, and trace back to where the source of the problem lies.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I did run in debug mode expecting to get detailed error but only thing I get also that ASSERT message in the debug mode is a dialog box saying the application closed in an unexpected way

Comment: Running in debug mode doesn't make an error appear.  You need to step through the code until the assert is triggered.  Once you find that point then you can analyze the code in that area to see if you can find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you run your program in a debugger, it will stop on the assertion and you'll be able to examine the stack trace. For example with this program in GDB :

```
#include <QList>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

   QList<int> my_list;
   my_list.append(1);
   my_list.pop_back(); // 1
   my_list.pop_back(); // 2

   return 0;
}
```

When you run it :

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/leiaz/tmp/qttest/build/proj 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qlist.h, line 321

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff61275f8 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

The assertion stop the debugger, and you can ask for the stack trace :

```
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  0x00007ffff61275f8 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6128a7a in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff6dc11e1 in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff6dbc34e in qt_assert(char const*, char const*, int) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00000000004060aa in QList<int>::removeLast (this=0x7fffffffe4d0)
    at /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qlist.h:321
#5  0x0000000000405de0 in QList<int>::pop_back (this=0x7fffffffe4d0)
    at /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qlist.h:337
#6  0x0000000000405ad4 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe5d8) at /home/leiaz/tmp/qttest/main.cc:9
```

You can see `removeLast` was called by `pop_back` and my code start at frame 6 :

```
(gdb) frame 6
#6  0x0000000000405ad4 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe5d8) at /home/leiaz/tmp/qttest/main.cc:9
9          my_list.pop_back(); // 2
```

Here you can examine the values of other variables in that frame.

If you are using Qt Creator see [Viewing Call Stack Trace](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html#viewing-call-stack-trace).

Comment: The first ouput was what I was expecting. I couldn't manage the open a debug build outside Qt. So instead of `gdb myfile.exe` I should do it inside the Qt cretor. Viewing the stack doesn't result in same behavior. The code you have posted as example ran and crash with an Microsoft Visual C++ runtime error and only a `ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore/qlist.h, line 321
`  in the console output window. The call stack trace is empty in the Qt creator. It isn't when I ran this code: `char *p = 0; *p = 'a';`

Comment: Someway debugger isn't catching the assert() failure in that case

Comment: To make it shorter, if I ran the code with the qlist from your example, it does crash with the same error message as in my question. The stack view look like this: http://prntscr.com/9ztq44 but If I ran `char *p = 0; *p = 'a';` it looks like exactly what I wanted http://prntscr.com/9ztq7m

Comment: The debugger stops on the SIGABRT signal, but maybe the Microsoft runtime catches the signal ? I don't use Windows. There is also a "Put a breakpoint on abort()" in Qt Creator's options which will make it stop on the call to abort() before the signal is raised. Or is the Microsoft error the one asking you if you want to start a debugger ? You could perhaps ask about configuring and using that.

Comment: I guess it's the issue: MS runtime catches this assert's signal so debug didn't know anything about. It isn't the dialog asking me to open the debugger, this just show a error message like the "application finished unexpectly" or so and end the application. I'll try make the debugger inside Qt catch that signal rather MS runtime

Answer (score 1):

> Like what line exactly in the source code is using it (from search, no direct call to removeLast() done). Is this possible?

Unfortunately `assert()` or `Q_ASSERT()` macros just show that the conditions were wrong, not which code was causing these conditions.

Especially if called many times and/or from many places, assertions aren't very helpful to detect what code actually was causing it.

---

You can set a conditional breakpoint for the `isEmpty()` condition, if that's well supported with your debugger.

You can also set a breakpoint in the standard `abort()` function, if you have access to the debug symbols.

---

If there's not, and if you have full access to the source code (which you have for a function inlined in a header) you can work around that deficiency. The way I'm usually going, is to change such code temporarily to

```
void removeLast() 
{ 
   if(isEmpty()) { // <<<<<<<<<<< Put an encapsulating if clause here
       return;  // <<<<<<<<<<<< set breakpoint     
   }
   Q_ASSERT(!isEmpty()); erase(--end());
}
```

and set a debugger breakpoint. When the breakpoint is hit while running the code from the debugger, I'll examine the call stack to see where this came from.

Comment: Does it make a difference that this a Qt function from the library and not the OP's code?

Comment: @NathanOliver: it does, because you're not supposed to modify Qt to debug a problem in your code.

Comment: @NathanOliver Of cause that makes a difference. Edited my answer a bit. Though that technique was particularly helpful, where I was able to change the source code. Otherwise conditional breakpoints might be helpful.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OK.  I just wanted to point out the the assert was not in the OP's code.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's just an ugly hack for debugging. I've learned it's going to be useful with debugging code written by a team colleague who thinks assertions are a golden hammer for debugging and replacing (not applicable) exceptions with them. One can place a breakpoint at  the standard `abort()` as well, to see the stack trace, but I don't like that so much.

Comment: Simply run the application in a debugger. Tripping over an assert will stop the debugger and you'll have the stack trace to examine. No need of modifying anything.

Comment: @peppe _"Tripping over an assert ..."_ isn't that much fun during debugging if the function is called every 10ms constantly in your software :-P ...

Comment: Sorry, with "trip over" I meant tripping (as in falling to the ground) when the assertion fails. :)